# Linking Custom Post Types in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have three Custom Post Types in Wordpress: artists, writers, stories

Is it possible to "link" the posts? For example, if a **story** is written by a **writer** and illustrated by an **artist**, I would like to show in the **story** page a picture of the **writer**  (linked to the writer's page) and other stories illustrated by the **artist**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You probably want a custom single page template.

Adding a new template for those post types is easy. You can add a new template for each post type, like "single-artist.php" in which you put together the page to display the artist info. On the "single-story.php" you can arrange it so that the appropriate links are added where necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Posts 2 Posts Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/)

It gives you the chance to make relationships between post types.
I used it to link Clients to Projects and it worked like a charm.

P.S.: The answer given earlier will be needed to, you will need to make templates to display this all.

Comment: This plugin is currently unsupported, though the author has offered it to others to take over according to the WP plugin page